# Interaction of custom JavaScript and Flot

Tags: javascript, html, flot

I'm having a variety of issues with a site that I'm constructing in an effort to teach myself JavaScript.  Please keep in mind while reading this that I am an old Fortraner.  I will attempt to make each of these issues exceptionally clear in case others also wish to learn from them.  All silly mistakes are my own.

#### Issue #1: `<input type="number" ...>` contents not passed to JavaScript

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
  <form id="pendulum">
    <table class="form">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><span class="rollover">Initial angle<span>0.0 &le; <i>&theta;</i> &le; 1.6</span></span>, $\theta_0$, of the mass:</label>
          <input type="number" name="theta0" id="theta0" value="0.1" min="0.0" max="1.6" step="0.1"> rad
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><span class="rollover">Ratio<span>1.0 &le; <i>g</i>/<i>L</i> &le; 10.0</span></span> of $\frac{g}{L}$:</label>
          <input type="number" name="read_ratio" id="read_ratio" value="9.0" min="1.0" max="10.0" step="0.1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><span class="rollover">Initial angular velocity<span>0.0 &le; <i>&omega;</i> &le; 6.0</span></span>, $\omega_0$, of the mass:</label>
          <input type="number" name="omega_read" id="omega_read" value="0.0" min="0.0" max="6.0" step="0.1"> rad/sec
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><span class="rollover">Time-step<span>0.001 &le; <i>dt</i> &le; 0.1</span></span>, $dt$, of the system:</label>
          <input type="number" name="dt_read" id="dt_read" value="0.01" min="0.001" max="0.1" step="0.001"> sec
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Period of the pendulum: <span id="output"></span> sec
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Evaluate" onclick="amp()">
    <a class="js" href="amp.js">Download the JavaScript</a><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function amp() {
  "use strict";
  var i_max,
    m,
    g,
    pendulum,
    f_osc,
    theta,
    omega,
    a,
    e,
    de,
    time,
    pi,
    theta0,
    read_ratio,
    const0,
    T,
    result,
    message,
    omega_read,
    dt_read,
    dt,
    i;
  i_max = 500;
  m = 1.0;
  g = 9.8;
  f_osc = 0.0;
  pendulum = document.forms.pendulum;
  theta = [];
  omega = [];
  a = [];
  e = [];
  de = [];
  time = [];
  pi = Math.acos(-1.0);
  theta0 = pendulum.elements.theta0;
  theta[0] = theta0;
  read_ratio = pendulum.elements.read_ratio;
  const0 = read_ratio;
  T = 2 * pi * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(const0, -1));
  result = T.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
  omega_read = pendulum.elements.omega_read;
  omega[0] = omega_read;
  dt_read = pendulum.elements.dt_read;
  dt = dt_read;
  e[0] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[0], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[0], 2));
  time[0] = 0.0;
  i = 0;
  do {
    f_osc = -const0 * Math.sin(theta[i]);
    a[i] = f_osc / m;
    e[i] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[i], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[i], 2));
    de[i] = e[i] - e[0];
    theta[i + 1] = theta[i] + omega[i] * dt + 0.5 * a[i] * dt * dt;
    f_osc = -const0 * Math.sin(theta[i + 1]);
    a[i + 1] = f_osc / m;
    omega[i + 1] = omega[i] + 0.5 * (a[i + 1] + a[i]) * dt;
    e[i] = 0.5 * (Math.pow(omega[i + 1], 2) + const0 * Math.pow(theta[i + 1], 2));
    de[i] = e[i] - e[0];
    time[i + 1] = time[i] + dt;
    i = i + 1;
  } while (i < i_max);
  return time;
  return theta;
  return omega;
  return e;
}
```

I did a simple test before this using a linear function.  (For the curious, this current script models a simple pendulum.)  My simple test seemed to work; this doesn't.  I have no idea why not.  I want to return arrays of `time`, `theta`, `omega`, and `e`.  But JSLint screams bloody murder when I do all those `return` statements.

#### Issue #2: Flot unaware of passed arrays?

The next task I wish to perform is to take the interesting data of `time`, `theta`, `omega`, and `e` and plot it using Flot.  However, I'm uncertain whether this information is being passed correctly to the Flot script.  The error console of Chrome, for example, doesn't seem to complain, but being new to JavaScript, I'm uncertain as to the best practice of making this kind of "sanity check".

JavaScript:

```
function doPlot(position,time,theta,omega,e) {
  $.plot("#placeholder", [
    {
      data: [time, theta],
      label: "Angle (rad)",
      yaxis: 1,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      data: [time, omega],
      label: "Angular Velocity (rad/sec)",
      yaxis: 2,
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      data: [time, e],
      label: "Energy (J)",
      yaxis: 3,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ],
    {
      yaxes: [ { alignTicksWithAxis: position == "left" ? 1 : null } ],
      legend: { position: "ne" }
    }
  );
};
```

A secondary issue is the correct syntax of plotting arrays of *x* and *y* data.  The Flot documentation doesn't seem overly clear on this point.  What's shown in the above code is my current best guess, but seeing as it doesn't work at all, it's obviously wrong.

#### Issue #3: Colored axes in Flot?

As shown in Issue #2, I have a plot with multiple *y*-axes.  For readability, I would like to color axes 2 and 3 with the corresponding color used to plot the data.  The most I've found on this issue is [here](http://ekasiswanto.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/how-to-change-axis-color-in-flot/).  I don't understand what's being done there, though.

I know this is a lot, but I've tried to cover a lot of ground in the interest of efficiency, and also with the hope that this will help others who are attempting the same thing.

---

#### Update

jrouillard, thanks for all your help.  Your advice on the `return` statements was most informative.  I've also reformatted my data like so (JavaScript):

```
theta_plot[i + 1] = [time[i + 1], theta[i + 1]];
omega_plot[i + 1] = [time[i + 1], omega[i + 1]];
e_plot[i + 1] = [time[i + 1], e[i + 1]];

...

return [theta_plot, omega_plot, e_plot];
```

Regarding Issue #3, after some better searching around, I came across [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CxhhT/).  (There are multiple versions of the Flot documentation out there; maybe I was looking at the wrong one.)  This is a much better alternative to what I originally planned.  After some corrections (JavaScript):

```
function doPlot(position,theta_plot,omega_plot,e_plot) {
  $.plot("#placeholder", [
    {
      data: theta_plot,
      /*label: "Angle (rad)",*/
      yaxis: 1,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      data: omega_plot,
      /*label: "Angular Velocity (rad/sec)",*/
      yaxis: 2,
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      data: e_plot,
      /*label: "Energy (J)",*/
      yaxis: 3,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ],
    {
      yaxes: [
        {
          position: "left",
          axisLabel: "Angle (rad)",
          axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        {
          position: "left",
          axisLabel: "Angular Velocity (rad/sec)",
          axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        {
          position: "left",
          axisLabel: "Energy (J)",
          axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        { alignTicksWithAxis: position == "left" ? 1 : null }
      ]
    }
  );
  $(".yaxisLabel").css("color","red");
  $(".y2axisLabel").css("color","green");
  $(".y3axisLabel").css("color","blue");
};
doPlot("left");
```

I don't yet know whether this will accomplish what I would like because it still won't plot when I load the page.  Right now this part returns `NaN` (JavaScript):

```
read_ratio = pendulum.elements.read_ratio;
//read_ratio = 9.0;
const0 = read_ratio;
T = 2 * pi * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(const0, -1));
result = T.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
```

However, when a test value is hard-coded, it works and returns the expected value to `Period of the pendulum: <span id="output"></span> sec`.

And why the rest of the script doesn't work is still a mystery.  Error console provides no clues.  And ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**Issue 1:**

If you want multiple returns, you should gather them in an array.

```
return [time, theta, omega, e];
```

You could also return an object with defined property according your variables:

```
{time: time, theta: theta, omega: omega, e: e}
```

I didnt test your code, though, so there might be another problem.

---

**Issue 2:**

the data is not formatted correctly. You will need to extract your arrays to create a proper data array.

this is your current array (with fake data) :

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

What you want to do is something in this format :

```
[[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5], [6,6]]
```

(the first point being the x-axis and the second point the y-axis)

---

**Issue3:**

I didnt read much of the blog post which goes into details of the inside of the flot code. That souldn't help a beginner.
It does state that you can access the color of the axes with the color option in the axis options.

From the doc:

```
Customizing the axes:
    xaxis, yaxis: {
           ...
          color: null or color spec

          ...
     }
```

> The "color" option determines the color of the line and ticks for the
>   axis, and 
>        defaults to the grid color with transparency. For more fine-grained control you can
>        also set the color of the ticks separately with "tickColor".
>        You can customize the font and color used to draw the axis tick labels with CSS or
>        directly via the "font" option. When "font" is null - the default - each tick label is
>        given the 'flot-tick-label' class. For compatibility with Flot 0.7 and earlier the 
>        labels are also given the 'tickLabel' class, but this is deprecated and scheduled
>        to be removed with the release of version 1.0.0.

So the color option for the lines and css for the labels

**EDIT:**

The "right" documentation can be found on http://www.flotcharts.org/, along with multiple relevant examples and officials (and maintained) plugins.

The jsfiddle you provided is quite old (the flot version is 0.7, we are at 0.8.3) but it seems the axislabel plugin still works with the newest flot.

here is your example with mockup data:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2yDJ/

I didnt change a thing except the fake data, so there might be a problem with your data. Are you sure you have proper arrays ?
Can you, before you return the array, console.log them ? (console.log(some variable) will write some variable in the console)

EDIT2: for your NaN problem, it might be that your readratio is actually a string. You should parseInt() it to be sure, and console.log it.

Comment: jrouillard, please see the above update for a detailed reply.

Comment: jrouillard, please know that I really appreciate all your help. I think I may be zeroing-in on the problem. Perhaps JS does not know I want to work with floats?  So, following the bouncing ball: `<input type="number" name="read_ratio" id="read_ratio" value="9.0" min="1.0" max="10.0" step="0.1">`, then `read_ratio = pendulum.elements.read_ratio;`, then `const0 = parseFloat(read_ratio);`, then `T = 2 * pi * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(const0.toFixed(1), -1));`, then `result = T.toFixed(2);`, and finally `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;`.

Comment: ...seems like this _should_ work, but no, still returns `NaN`.

Comment: By the way, `console.log(read_ratio);` returns `<input type="number" name="read_ratio" id="read_ratio" value="9.0" min="1.0" max="10.0" step="0.1">`. That's confusing...

Comment: This is an html element.
Try: 
`readratio = $(readratio).val()`
or:
`readratio = $(readratio).attr('value')`

This will get the value attribute of your html element.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `read_ratio = pendulum.elements.read_ratio;` followed by `const0 = read_ratio.value;` reads the `value` from the form.